# Change Input Value using Pure JS on a React Webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am running a script on a react webpage. Simply trying to autofill some form elements.

I tried to change an input element's value and then click submit (sends a post request), but value I set is not in the request body.

what I expect is

```
{
   name:"example"
}
```

what I get is

```
{}
```

.

```
document.querySelector('input["name"]').value = "example"
document.querySelector('input["name"]').defaultValue = "example"
document.querySelector('input["name"]').setAttribute("value", "example")
```

I tried all of them but doesn't work. First one didn't change the element's value.
Third line was able to change element's value (I see that on the HTML) but when I submit, field are blank..

After I type some additional letters into input, field is filled.

```
document.querySelector('input["name"]').setAttribute("value", "example")
```

Let's say I execute this line than go to input add 'X'  so input is exampleX
request body is correct. I guess It is a kind of modern web app and it updates input value on changes but I couldn't figure out.

```
{
name: 'exampleX'
}
```

If I type with my hands -> request body is how it should be
[image]

If I run my script -> request body is empty.
[image]
Is there a way to solve this issue?